# Having html pages without an extension (aka 'pretty urls') render as html using netlify

Tags: netlify, static-html

I'm trying to use netlify to host a static site. I'm building the site using `wget -mk  http://hostname/` so I get a large number of static files, with links rewritten.

I'd like to push them to netlify and have that host the site.

Pages that end in .html are treated as html files and are displayed correctly.

Pages that have 'pretty urls' like `/about` are treated like text files, and the HTML markup is displayed.

I can't really rename all these files unless I add rewrites because there are external links to the site that I want to preserve.

I tried setting up a [`_headers`](https://www.netlify.com/docs/headers-and-basic-auth/) file but it wasn't clear what the order of operations was. Here's a sample `_headers` file:

```
/*.css
  Content-Type: text/css
/*.js
  Content-Type: text/javascript
/*.jpg
  Content-Type: image/jpg
/*.jpeg
  Content-Type: image/jpg
/*.png
  Content-Type: image/png
/*.gif
  Content-Type: image/gif
/*
  Content-Type: text/html
```

This treats everything as text/html. I could remove the last line, but then the files that are pretty are treated as text again.

Is the only solution to iterate all the files and mark them as html using the full path, which would make the `_headers` file look something like this:

```
/about
  Content-Type: text/html
/contact
  Content-Type: text/html
...
```

I looked in the netlify documentation and googled and wasn't able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem I ended up writing a shell script to generate the `_headers` file.

It looks like this:

```
find `pwd` -type f |grep  -v \\. |sed "s#`pwd`/##" > list
for i in `cat list`; do 
  echo "/$i" >> _headers; 
  echo "  Content-Type: text/html" >> _headers; 
done
rm list
```

I just check in the `_headers` file and all the files at pretty urls are treated as html.

Comment: Thanks for this! This didn't work as-is for me since the app directory name contains a "." (and thus all paths would be excluded). I ended up doing it in Ruby: 
`File.write("_headers", Dir["**/*"].select { |x| File.file?(x) }.reject { |x| x.include?(".") }.sort.map { |x| "/#{x}\n  Content-Type: text/html" }.join("\n"))`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to treat pages without extensions as html. Use the `--adjust-extension` option.

> If a file of type ‘application/xhtml+xml’ or ‘text/html’ is downloaded and the URL does not end with the regexp ‘.[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]?’, this option will cause the suffix ‘.html’ to be appended to the local filename.

See the [options section of the Wget Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTP-Options)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that doesn't deal with external links. I could add a redirect for all the pages, but at that point I might as well just generate the _headers file.